# NAT gateway set up doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-nat-gateway

I have implemented an environment for a Wordpress website. I have a loadbalncer (ALB) that is connected to an EC2 server plus an AutoScaling group(for failover).

As we need to update Wordpress and install some plugins on EC2 server, I need to set up NAT gateway to allow internet connection from wordpress server(ec2) to internet.

I have set up the NAT gateway like the following link:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

However I could not be able to reach the Website (DNS of ALB) afterward.

My Routetable set up looks like below:

```
                      Route                Subnets
Main Route Table        10.0.0.0/16 local       -
                     0.0.0.0/0   natgw

Public Route Table        10.0.0.0/16 local       10.0.10.0/24, 10.0.11.0/24  (ELB subnets)
                     0.0.0.0/0   igw

Private route B      10.0.0.0/16 local       10.0.20.0/24,10.0.30.0/24 (EC2 subnets)
                     0.0.0.0/0   natgw  

Private route C      10.0.0.0/16 local       10.0.21.0/24,10.0.31.0/24 (RDS subnets)
                     0.0.0.0/0   natgw
```

The Public route is assigned to two public subnets which are connected to the LoadBalancer.

The Private route B,C are assigned to private subnets: Web server()EC2 plus database-RDS.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There's only one route table per subnet. Why do you have four route tables? Suggest you provide a diagram of what instances / services are where.

Comment: What route table is the private instance in? Also did you place the NAT gateway in a public subnet?

Comment: @strongjz The Private route B,C are assigned to private instances which are sonncted to NAT Gateway, The LoadBalancer is assigned to Public subnets which are connected to Internet Gateway

Comment: I see you edited your question, but it's still quite unclear what your network setup is, which subnet servers are located in, and what route tables apply to what. [A diagram](https://cloudcraft.co/) might help, if you draw it effectively. You need to be a lot more clear if you want any help.

Comment: @Tim Yes, there is only one default route table per VPC however it is possibe to make more route tables when we want to separate public and private subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram shows the IGW subnets do not overlap with your NAT Gateway subnets. This is the issue. The NAT Gateway needs to be in a subnet with an attached IGW. This is true even though the NAT Gateway has a public ip (Elastic IP).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my NAT Gateway is in a public subnet(10.0.10.0/24). Is there something else that I'm missing in the set up?

Comment: Do you have any NACLs configured?

Comment: No, it is as default.

Answer (score 0):

> However I could not be able to reach the Website (DNS of ALB) afterward.

1. Is the ALB internet-facing (as opposed to internal)?
2. Does the security group on the ALB allow you to connect?

(Network packets from Internet via internet-facing ALB to EC2 instances and back ought not traverse a NAT gw).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the ALB is open for the internet. The Website has been set up with ALB before and it works fine. I just need to add NAT GW in order to do some updated on the server which is in a private subnet.